# Series with specific notation

Tags: series-expansion, custom-notation

I'm trying to get mathematicas `series` function to output a result that look like this:

[image]

instead of calculating the actual "values", like doing so here:

```
seriesfunc = Sin[x] Cos[x]/x
(* (Cos[x] Sin[x])/x *)

Series[seriesfunc, {x, 0, 5}]
(* 1-(2 x^2)/3+(2 x^4)/15+O[x]^6 *)
```

Is this possible? Yes, it is part of homework (or Calculus II exam actually), but I still think it's allowed here.

Answer (score 10):

I think [`SeriesCoefficient`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SeriesCoefficient.html) is what you want. Then you can use it to display formatted formulas

```
 series[expr_, x_, x0_] := Defer[expr = Sum[#, {n, 0, ∞}]] &[
  FullSimplify@SeriesCoefficient[expr, {x, x0, n}, Assumptions -> {n >= 0}] (x - x0)^n]

series[Sin[x] Cos[x]/x, x, 0]
```

[image]

Comment: You may want it elegantly typed, wrap TeXForm around the result and paste the results into a TeX word-processing system.

Answer (score 4):

If you hit `=` in a clean cell twice the cell will turn into a Wolfram Alpha cell, and you can ask it using the English language. It will give you the series expansion as well as a series representation:

[image: Taylor approximation through Wolfram Alpha]