# Force Mathematica to display `Series` in factorial notation

Tags: series-expansion, display, number-representation

The `Series` expansion for `Sin[Pi * x]` is

```
Series[Sin[Pi * x], {x, 0, 10}]
```

> Pi * x - (Pi^3 * x^3) /6 + (Pi^5 * x^5) /120 - (Pi^7 * x^7) /5040 +
> (Pi^9 * x^9) /362880 + O[x]^11

How can I make Mathematica display this using factorial notation? I'd prefer this to read

> Pi * xn - (Pi^3 * x^3) /3! + (Pi^5 * x^5) /5! - (Pi^7 * x^7) /7! +
> (Pi^9 * x^9) /9! + O[x]^11

I appreciate that the result in `InputForm` is

```
InputForm[Series[Sin[Pi * x], {x, 0, 10}]]
```

> SeriesData[x, 0, {  Pi, 0, Rational[-1, 6] Pi^3, 0, Rational[1, 120]
> Pi^5, 0, Rational[-1, 5040] Pi^7, 0, Rational[1, 362880] Pi^9}, 1,
> 11, 1]

So, equivalently, I'm after the output

> SeriesData[x, 0, {  Pi, 0, Rational[-1, Factorial[3]] Pi^3, 0, Rational[1, Factorial[5]]
> Pi^5, 0,    Rational[-1, Factorial[7]] Pi^7, 0, Rational[1, Factorial[9]] Pi^9}, 1,
> 11, 1]

Comment: [A related question.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/71589)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with some tinkering with `Inactive`, since that's one of the ways to prevent the factorial from evaluating:

```
factorialForm[s : HoldPattern @ SeriesData[x_, x0_, coeffList_List, n0_, n1_, 1]] :=
     With[{powRange = Range[n0, n0 + Length[coeffList] - 1]},
      SeriesData[x, x0,
       Divide[
        coeffList * Factorial[powRange],
        Map[Inactive[Factorial], powRange]
       ],
       n0, n1, 1
      ]
     ];
factorialForm[Series[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}]]
```

> [image]

Instead of `Inactive[Factorial]` there are other holding constructs you can use, like `Defer[Factorial[#]]&` or `HoldForm[Factorial[#]] &`. The nice thing about `Inactive` is that you can easily get rid of it again with `Activate`.

I only implemented this for `SeriesData[__, 1]`. You'd have to do a little thinking if you to make it work for other step sizes.

Comment: That's a great answer +1.

Answer (score 6):

Also possible is:

```
$Post = #1 /. HoldPattern[SeriesData[Verbatim[z__]]] :> SeriesData[z] /. 
 Rational[a_, b_] :> 
   With[{invf = Reduce`FactorialInverse[b][[1]]}, 
    a/HoldForm[invf!]] & ;
```

Then

```
Series[Sin[Pi*x],{x,0,10}]
```

displays as desired.

Comment: `Reduce\`FactorialInverse` is a bit more direct. +1

Comment: @ciao Thank's! I was looking for this function but was not aware where to find it.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a function you can use to replace `Series[]`:

```
inactiveSeries[f_, {x_, x0_, n_}] := Module[{kk, tc},
        tc[kk_] = Inactivate[Evaluate[SeriesCoefficient[f, {x, x0, kk}]], 
                             Factorial | Gamma | Pochhammer];
        Sum[tc[kk] (x - x0)^kk, {kk, 0, n}] + O[x, x0]^(n + 1)]
```

For example,

```
inactiveSeries[Sin[π x], {x, 0, 10}]
```

[image: output 1]

A more complicated example:

```
inactiveSeries[Hypergeometric1F1Regularized[-1/3, 1/5, x], {x, 0, 3}]
```

[image: output 2]