# Series solution of a differential equation

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, output-formatting, series-expansion

Calculate the series solution of a differential equation:

$\frac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{~d} x}=-y-x$, ( $\left.y\right|_{x=0}=2$)

`AsymptoticDsolvevalue` can calculate the series solution of a differential equation, but it can only get the result of a finite term:

```
AsymptoticDSolveValue[{y'[x] == -y[x] - x, y[0] == 2}, 
 y[x], {x, 0, 10}]
```

> 2 - 2 x + x^2/2 - x^3/6 + x^4/24 - x^5/120 + x^6/720 - x^7/5040 + 
> x^8/40320 - x^9/362880 + x^10/3628800

```
AsymptoticDSolveValue[{y'[x] == -y[x] - x, y[0] == 2}, 
 y[x], {x, 0, n}]
```

> AsymptoticDSolveValue[{Derivative[1][y][x] == -x - y[x], y[0] == 2},
> y[x], {x, 0, n}]

How to get the series solution of with n term of a differential equation?

$\frac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{~d} x}=-y-x$, ( $\left.y\right|_{x=0}=2$)

result:

$\begin{aligned} y &=2-2 x+\frac{1}{2 !} x^{2}-\frac{1}{3 !} x^{3}+\cdots+(-1)^{n} \frac{1}{n !} x^{n}+\cdots \\ &=1-x+\left[1-x+\frac{1}{2 !} x^{2}-\frac{1}{3 !} x^{3}+\cdots+(-1)^{n} \frac{1}{n !} x^{n}+\cdots\right] \end{aligned}$

$=1-x+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{n} \frac{1}{n !} x^{n}$

I tried to solve this problem with `FindSequenceFunction`, but the output-formatting of the result is not factorial.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
sol[n_] := 
 AsymptoticDSolveValue[{y'[x] == -y[x] - x, y[0] == 2}, 
  y[x], {x, 0, n}]
Table[sol[n], {n, 1, 17}] // FullSimplify

FindSequenceFunction[%,n]
```

> (E^-x (-E^x Gamma[1 + n] + E^x x Gamma[1 + n] -
> Gamma[1 + n, -x]))/Gamma[1 + n]

Is there a simpler way or not to use `FindSequenceFunction` to get factorial results?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
a = AsymptoticDSolveValue[{y'[x] == -y[x] - x, y[0] == 2}, y[x], {x, 0, 20}]
(*    2 - 2 x + x^2/2 + ... + x^20/2432902008176640000    *)

c = CoefficientList[a, x]
(*    {2, -2, 1/2, ..., 1/2432902008176640000}    *)

cc[n_] = FindSequenceFunction[c[[3 ;;]], n - 1] // FullSimplify
(*    (-1)^n/Gamma[1 + n]    *)
```

The problem is that the first two coefficients don't fit the pattern. Looking for a pattern for $n\ge2$ works with `FindSequenceFunction` though.

```
c[[1]] + c[[2]] x + Sum[cc[n] x^n, {n, 2, ∞}]
(*    2 - 2 x + E^-x (1 - E^x + E^x x)    *)
```

To extend the `Sum` explicitly to all $\mathbb{N}_0$, we can do

```
(c[[1]] - cc[0]) + (c[[2]] - cc[1]) x + Defer[Sum][cc[n] x^n, {n, 0, ∞}]
(*    1 - x + Sum[((-1)^n x^n)/Gamma[1 + n], {n, 0, ∞}]    *)
```

Alternatively, [`FindGeneratingFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindGeneratingFunction.html) removes one intermediate step:

```
c[[1]] + c[[2]] x + x^2 FindGeneratingFunction[c[[3 ;;]], x]
(*    2 - 2 x + E^-x (1 - E^x + E^x x)    *)
```

Comment: Thanks!` c = MonomialList[a, {x}, "DegreeLexicographic"];d = Reverse[c];e = FindSequenceFunction[d[[3 ;;]], n - 1] // FullSimplify;FullSimplify[e, n \[Element] Integers && n > 0, 
 ComplexityFunction -> ((LeafCount@# + 
      10 Count[#, _Gamma | _Pochhammer, {0, \[Infinity]}]) &)]`

Comment: The outform of the solution I want to get is $1-x+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n} \frac{1}{n !} x^{n}$.

Comment: @lotus2019 see update

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

```
series[expr_, x_, x0_] := 
 Defer[Sum[#, {n, 0, ∞}]] &[
  FullSimplify@SeriesCoefficient[expr, {x, x0, n}, Assumptions -> {n >= 0}] (x - x0)^n]

DSolveValue[{y'[x] == -y[x] - x, y[0] == 2}, y[x], x] // Simplify
% /. E^a_ :> series[E^a, x, 0]
```

`series` is based on https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/71593/1871

Comment: This is really a good way. The solution of the differential equation is obtained first, and then transformed into series. Thanks!